# Multiple <form> tags in different locations with the same target iframe?

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I have an iframe in the content area:

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" frameBorder="0" height="200" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

I have a submit-button under it:

```
<form action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And I want some checkboxes in another area:

```
<form action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
<input type="checkbox" name="option">
</form>
```

But it doesn't work, the submit-button works but it doesn't send the checkbox.

I can't put everything in one -tag because I want the checkbox in a sidepanel of the main-view and the submit-button on a page that is in another page. (Loaded per ajax? I'm using frameworks7 btw.)

Is it not possible with different form-tags or is it because of the ajax thingy?

**EDIT1**: I managed to build an example for easier understanding with plunker, it doesn't work with php and I don't have a webspace right now, but you get the idea.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dfqzCbeQWgg9hAyCpGpb

Comment: Listen to the submit event of the form and copy values from the second form to the one being submitted (into hidden fields)

Comment: Sounds logical, but I'm bad with js and I hoped it would be possible with plain html^^' I just don't know how to do that TT

Comment: Even if it is loaded through AJAX, you can wrap your entire page with a <form> tag

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't worked :O The whole page didn't load. Are you sure?

Comment: @Fox https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDY5OTc0XzI1MjAyMDY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE 2

To get a cleaner result without the stale cache confusing tests I have updated it, please review newest update:

http://plnkr.co/edit/34KOyh9rIEGV3bXNsD9F?p=preview

---

## UPDATE

Now that I was provided with a very complete and nicely coded demo, I have solved your problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2I1Q2swIXmFfynalaLB?p=preview

**Note:** I'm using a test server, so the cache may be stale. Just change the `action` by adding a number to the end.

**Example**

change:

```
http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/so_post_chk
```

to:

```
http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/so_post_chk1
```

- When the checkbox is checked, your result should be `cache=on`
- When the checkbox is not checked, your result should be `cache=`

---

You could assign one or more inputs (usually `type="hidden"`) outside of the forms and collect whatever data from anywhere on the page regardless of which form it originated from.

http://plnkr.co/edit/er5RoJ049xSBwtR7gtTI?p=preview

This demo revolves around a simple JS function:

```
    function toOutput(x) {
      var str = x.toString();
      var out4 = document.getElementById('out4');
      out4.value += str;
    }
```

Note the special condition for checkboxes:

```
    if(this.checked) {
      toOutput(this.value);
      text1.value += this.value;
    };
```

It's needed because when the `click` event is triggered on a checkbox, it is considered on every click checked and unchecked. I assume that the checkbox value is collected when it's actually checked.

Comment: That is very nice, I actually understand it somehow xD But I don't manage to get the collecting formfield to be hidden and it doesn't seem to fit in my layout. I added an example inside that plunker thingy, maybe you understand what I mean :D

Comment: Sorry to mislead you, I mentioned hidden inputs in passing (hence the parentheses). On the contrary, `form4` is the collecting element which is in plain view, no hidden shenanigans here.

Comment: So it's not possible that way without a visible collecting element?

Comment: Of course it's possible, I just showed you one way visible (my old demo), and one way hidden (the new demo). Nice looking app, btw.

Comment: Awesome, that completely solves my problem :) Will test it later, I'm at work. Thank you! The app is made with framework7 btw (http://www.idangero.us/framework7/), it's very easy, so no credits for me ^^

Comment: When you check the checkbox and submit [cache] is "on", but when you uncheck it it stays "on". When you check it again, its [cache] => onon.

Comment: @Fox Follow the directions for changing `action`, the test server can be *stale*. That's why I suggested that you use your server for `action`, because you'll have control of cache, headers, etc.

Comment: @Fox The behavior at least on your side is working. It takes an hour for the server's cache to clear, so what you see is an accumulation of the data. Ex. 1st checked post: 'on', 2nd unchecked post: '', 3rd checked post:'onon', ... see the pattern?

Comment: @Fox to resolve this caching (it is kinda lame), I have updated the checkbox `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked) {toOutput(this.value);} else {toOutput('');}" value="on"/>` See new Update

Comment: OMG, it took me over an hour to realize that on phones `onclick` doesn't get fired with a tap.... Changed it to `onchange` and it works. But now you have to use `cache.value = str;` so when I want to add more checkboxes I have to create an separate hidden field and change the function, right?

Comment: Well look on the brightside, you are still progressing forward ;-) You don't have to use hidden fields, but imho that's the best suited element. There are of course other ways to store data: var but they only live as long as the function runtime (unless you use a closure or var is global), a cookie, localstorage, database, etc. Remember to assign each of them different ids.

Answer (score 2):

**I got option**  onsubmit form ...
Try it:

Create test.php file:

```
<form id="myForm" action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
<input id="cbopt" type="checkbox" name="option" value="option" checked="checked">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var y = document.createElement("input");
y.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
y.setAttribute("value", "option");
y.setAttribute("name", "option");
y.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(y);


var x = document.getElementById("cbopt").name;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

var z = document.forms.length;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
</script>
```

Code for  includes/action.php :

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" frameBorder="0" height="150" width="555" src="about:blank">
<p id="demo"></p>
</iframe>

<?php 
//$site = $_POST['doorde'];
//$url = $_POST['doordie1'];
$opt = $_POST['option'];

echo  $opt;

?>
```

Try and comment me ...

Comment: Don't listen to a click on the submit button, listen to the submit event on the form instead. That way, it will also work when the form is submitted using enter

Comment: Thx for the reply! I'm quite bad with js and doing hard with understanding what it does. I don't understand why you put the iframe into the action.php. I added an example of what I'm trying to do, maybe with that you could explain it for dummys like me? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do, copy the values from one form to the other before submitting, making sure you remove fields added previously when you submit again.

```
<form action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe" id="myform">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="includes/action.php" method="post" target="my_iframe" id="otherform">
   <input type="checkbox" name="option">
</form>

<iframe name="my_iframe" frameBorder="0" height="200" src="about:blank"></iframe>

<script>
function copyFormFieldsIntoHiddenFields(from, to) {
    var elementsAdded = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < from.elements.length; i++) {
        var nodeToCopy = from.elements[i];
        // Unchecked checkboxes do not get sent to server
        if (nodeToCopy.type != "checkbox" || nodeToCopy.checked) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.type = "hidden";
            hiddenField.name = nodeToCopy.name;
            hiddenField.value = nodeToCopy.value;
            to.appendChild(hiddenField);
            elementsAdded.push(hiddenField);
        }
    }
    return elementsAdded;
}

var addedFields = [];
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {

    // Remove any fields that were previously added
    for (var i = 0; i < addedFields.length; i++) {
       this.removeChild(addedFields[i]);
    }

    // Add the new hidden fields
    var copyFrom = document.getElementById('otherform');
    addedFields = copyFormFieldsIntoHiddenFields(copyFrom, this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried it, works fine :) But the same problem: When I discheck the checkbox it stays checked in the submit-form.

Comment: Ha, that makes sense,  I should have added a note that there would be bugs because this assumed there would be only one submission

Comment: Nah, I want to build on it and my js-knowledge isn't good enough that I can fix it TT I tried to add an else wich removes the input field in case it isn't checked, but it doesn't work: `else { to.removeChild(nodeToCopy.id);}`

Comment: @Fox Added a fix,  remove the extra fields before the next submit.

Comment: The elementsAdded array gets only a pointer like in lua tables? This starts getting complicated lel, but thx! Will try it tomorrow, it's late here :)

Comment: Yes, everything that is not a primitive is always passed a "pointer" to the data, not a copy of the data.

Comment: It works, thx :D But the idea of zer00ne also works fine and it seems to be more lightweight. I don't know wich to use now :O

Comment: @Fox The reason mine is less lightweight is because is because it's generic so that it works with a second form containing any field elements. I refuse to write code that only works for a basic case but you use whatever is best for your app